# Parent component passes empty data in props to child component when having structurized state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm absolutely new to React and can't deal with following:

In my React app there is parent App component which has this constructor

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        excercises: [],
        current: {
            excercise: '',
            muscle_part: '',
            weight: ''
        }
    }
}
```

App component renders this AddExcercise component

```
class AddExcercise extends React.Component {
render(){
    return(
        <form className='AddExcercise' onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
            <input type='text' name='current.excercise' value={this.props.excercise} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
            <input type='text' name='current.muscle_part' value={this.props.muscle_part} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
            <input type='text' name='current.weight' value={this.props.weight} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
            <input type='submit' value='Přidat' />
        </form>
    )
}
```

like this

```
<AddExcercise handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            excercise={this.state.current.excercise}
            muscle_part={this.state.current.muscle_part}
            weight={this.state.current.weight}/>
```

handleChange function should change the current property of state in App component like this:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

And then the change in form when submitted should push the current properties via this function (I've added log of the props, it returns an empty object):

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.props);
    let newExc = {
        excercise: this.state.current.excercise,
        muscle_part: this.state.current.muscle_part,
        weight: this.state.current.weight
    }
    let excercises = this.state.excercises.slice();
    excercises.push(newExc);
    this.setState({excercises: excercises});
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

When I submit the form, it logs empty object, the state of the app looks like this:
[image: state of the app]

Any ideas how to solve it with current App state structure?

Here is a pen of the app [pen of the app](https://codepen.io/vlisak/pen/qBKaBdQ)

Comment: you just have to get as `this.props.exercise` from `props` `current` isn't required \...

Comment: It doesn't change the current property of state, instead it creates new properties like this, so the inputs in form stays blank because the current is still empty:

current
:
{excercise: "", muscle_part: "", weight: ""}
excercise
:
""
muscle_part
:
""
weight
:
""
new entry
: 
""
current.excercise
:
"f"
current.muscle_part
:
"f"
current.weight
:
"f"

excercises
:
[]

Comment: did you try as I mentioned ?

Comment: Yes, in each input I changed value attribute to value={this.props.excercise} and so on

Comment: didn't it work ? if so I would suggest to `log` the `props` and see how is the structure

Comment: It logs empty object, just "{}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249346/discussion-between-vlastimil-lisak-and-kch).